# How can I remove the default color ( blue ) of windows when focus on TabItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a `TabControl` that will have two tab items and I created a style for this `TabControl`.

However, I've a problem when focus on a TabItem that is not selected as image shown , the background of this `TabItem` will have a blue color .

I would like to remove this blue color as image shown from the `TabItem` when do a focus on it.

I've tried many ways to do this but any of these methods works for me.

```
    <TabControl Style="{StaticResource newStyle}">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
            <TabItem.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
               
            </TabItem.Style>
            
        </TabItem>
        
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
            <TabItem.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

            </TabItem.Style>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

**newStyle Style :**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="newStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0" />
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="RowDefinition0" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="RowDefinition1" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" x:Name="border" Margin="5" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="true" Panel.ZIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="4,0,0,0">
                            <!--<TabPanel.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" />
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </TabPanel.LayoutTransform>
                        <TabPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" />
                                <RotateTransform />
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </TabPanel.RenderTransform>-->
                        </TabPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4" x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="border" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="2,2,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="border" Value="0,0,2,2" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="4,-2.5,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="border" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">

                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="border" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="border" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="border" Value="0,2,2,0" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0,2,2,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="4,0,-2.5,0" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="border" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="2,0,0,2" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="border" Value="0,2,2,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="-3,0,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template for the `TabItem`. Below is the default one. Modify the `TabItem.MouseOver.Background` resource and/or the triggers as per your requirements.

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource newStyle}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItem.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#F0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#E5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Static.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Background" Color="Red" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Border" Color="#7EB4EA"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Background" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Border" Color="#D9D9D9"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,6,2"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="mainBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Margin="0">
                                <Border x:Name="innerBorder" Background="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,0,-2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,-2,-2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-2,-2,-2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1" />

    <TabItem Header="Tab 2" />
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I've test your code and I'm getting the same issue . Sorry but this won't works for me.

Comment: You didn't change the `TabItem.MouseOver.Background` then? Read the answer once more...

Comment: If you copy and paste my edited sample markup, you should see that the `TabItem` turns red when you hover it.